# Randomize order for DataMapper records

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sinatra, datamapper

I'm simply looking to **return DataMapper records in a random order**.

Here is my model (using DataMapper with sqlite3 database):

```
class Movie
  include DataMapper::Resource
  DataMapper::Property::String.length(255)

  property :id, Serial
  property :title, String
  property :img, String
  property :description, String
  property :year, String
  property :created_at, DateTime

  has n, :votes 
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And here is how I'm returning the records (Sinatra)

```
get '/' do
  @movies = Movie.all # <-- What should this look like?
  haml :home
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do this (based [on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039902/how-does-rubys-sort-by-rand-work)):

```
@movies = Movie.all.sort_by{rand}
```

Also, that same post [suggests](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-shuffle-21) `Array#shuffle!` which would take the array and shuffle it around so possibly something like this:

```
@movies = Movie.all.shuffle #no ! since you are not replacing the Array; not sure if DM supports it
```

--or--

```
@movies = Movie.all
@movies.shuffle!
```

Comment: How is `@movies = Movie.all.shuffle!` different from `@movies = Movie.all; @movies.shuffle!` ?

Comment: @padde It is subtle, but it is `@movies = Movie.all.shuffle`... no exclamation point. The `!` means that you take what was in the original var and overwrite it. Since there is nothing to overwrite in `@movies` in the `@movies = Movie.all.shuffle` segment I left off the `!`. I was just not sure if DM inherited that method so offered an alternative if it did not work.

Comment: I mean in your last example, you're really just writing `Movie.all.shuffle!` in two lines. You're still calling the mutator on the return value of `Movie.all`. So there's no point in saying one should not call `Movie.all.shuffle!`. But since `Movie.all` just returns a copy it is ok either way, so never mind.

Comment: Also note that `shuffle` implements the Fisher-Yates algorithm directly in C, so this is the most efficient way to shuffle an array in Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this in SQL, for example:

```
class Movie
  # tons of other stuff here...

  def self.random
    repository(:default).adapter.select <<-SQL
      SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY RANDOM()
    SQL
  end
end
```

Then you can do

```
get '/' do
  @movies = Movie.random
  haml :home
end
```

Whey you use MySQL, you need to replace `RANDOM()` by `RAND()`. Please note, that the Objects returned by `Movie#random` are not `Movie` objects and read only, but you can read the attributes just like with `Movie` objects, e.g. `Movie.random.first.title` gets the title of the first random movie.

The big advantage is, if you have many records in your database and only want a handful of random `Movie`s, you don't have to fetch all Movies and sort them afterwards, but you can use an SQL query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 10
```

Or you could extend your method to something like this:

```
class Movie
  # tons of other stuff here...

  def self.random(opts={})
    query = "SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY RANDOM()"
    query << " LIMIT #{opts[:limit]}" unless opts[:limit].nil?
    repository(:default).adapter.select(query)
  end
end
```

which allows to write queries like this:

```
Movie.random              # get all movies sorted randomly
Movie.random(:limit => 5) # get five random movies
```

Comment: can you explain what `repository(:default).adapter.select` is doing before the sql statement?  thanks.

Comment: `repository(:default)` just selects the `:default` repository. You can work with multiple data stores in DataMapper (see http://datamapper.org/docs/misc.html) but this is irrelevant for most applications. `adapter` gets the corresponding adapter (for example the sqlite adapter in your case) dynamically, depending on what database you use. finally, `select` performs the query on the database.

Comment: thanks this looks good...and you believe it to be more performant that `Movie.all.shuffle` ?

Comment: @pruett: it is not necessarily more performant. what this shines at is pulling a few random entries from a large table in the database because the database queries are often the bottleneck. if you only have a few entries or always want to get all entries anyway, then @ScottJShea's solution with `shuffle` is much cleaner and simpler and i would stick to that.

Comment: awesome, thanks.  yes i checked his solution because it was easier and just what i needed, since i need to randomize and return all results.  thanks for providing feedback and answering my questions