# How does `sort_by` work with multiple fields?

Tags: ruby, sorting

In the following piece of code, `due_date` and `position` are optional fields, whereas `important` is a field which is always set to either `true` or `false`.

```
posts.sort_by do |post| 
  [post.due_date || 0, post.position || 0, post.important? ? 0 : 1]
end
```

I'm trying to figure out how multiple sort works. If `due_date` is present, then it takes precedence or sets it to zero. Why are we something setting it to zero here?

Comment: If you sort_by a collection words by word.length it compares word lengths. If you compare arrays, IIRC it walks the array until there's something `!=`, e.g., if the `due_date` isn't equal, that's the comparison. If it is, it's `position`, etc. You set something to zero as a way of providing a default value if there's nothing in that field.

Comment: arrays sort by the natural ordering of the first element; if there is a tie, those ties are sorted by the second element; etc.

Comment: Refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039902/how-does-rubys-sort-by-rand-work/2040025#2040025), that's not exactly your problem, but the solution may be of some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is nothing particularly about multiple comparison. If you compare arrays, each of the elements will be compared to the corresponding one in another array. If those values sometimes take numerical values, then they always have to be numerals. Numerals cannot be compared to `nil`, and doing so will raise an error. Defaulting them to zero is to ensure they are numerals. As long as you default them to a numeral, it will not raise an error. The particular choice of zero was based on where you want to position the entries with the missing values; you could have chosen infinity, negative infinity, etc for different results.

Comment: how should I handle datetime fields in that case. I cannot default them to zero or Time.now

Comment: You can create a dummy Time object with the Unix epoch.

Comment: How do I create that object, and what value would it be equal to.

Comment: `Time.new(0)`. It would be smaller than any other time object.